# Repetition data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have attendance table in SQLServer that has 3 fields (id,course,date) 
I want this table not to accept the same id in attendance for same date and course
but it can record id for different date or different course.

I try to add command for this condition in my stored procedure but doesn't work.

Comment: Where is your stored procedure?

Comment: Try adding a `Unique` constraint on the table across all three fields.

Comment: but i have fourth filed time (seconds) so what can i do
can i make constraint only for id & date & course

Comment: @user3340277 only include the id, date, and course in the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `Unique` constraint.

Try the following:

```
Alter Table Attendance
Add Constraint uq_WhateverNameYouWant Unique (id, course, date)
```

This will force the table to only accept unique values across all three of the fields.

**For example** If you have the following values in the table:

```
Id  Course  Date
1   101     2014-06-18
1   102     2014-06-18
2   101     2014-06-18
2   101     2014-06-19
```

If you tried to add this:

```
Id  Course  Date
1   103     2014-06-18
```

It would allow it.  But if you tried to add this:

```
Id  Course  Date
1   101     2014-06-18
```

It would fail, as that set of three values already exists.

Comment: but i don't want unique values for the three filed. no problem for repeating the id but when the date change or when the course change

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.  It would do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for your example but i have exactly in the table 5 fields (id & course & status & date & time(sec))
so the time will cause me a problem because it will not repeat can i make the constraint for id & date & course only

Comment: That's what this will do.  The `Unique (id, course, date)` is only concerned with a unique set of values across those three columns.  Any other column can be duplicated.